# Checking convolution property II of z transform

Tags: z-transform

I have two sequences x and y of lengths, say 5 and 10.  I multiply them in time domain element by element.  I get another sequence.  Now this as per the convolution theorem should be equal to the inverse z tranform of the convolution of the two z transforms of the original sequences.  Now, I know how to get the ZTs of the original sequences.  How do I get the convolution of  these ZTs?

Comment: As usual, I assume that the sequences are infinite in length, the non-given values are zeros and so I pad with zeros to make the lengths equal and proceed further with calculations.

Comment: It's not clear where you're running into trouble; try giving more details. As you noted, you need to convolve the two sequence, then inverse transform the result. You didn't really specify what part you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I got stuck up how to find the convolution in z-domain once I find the ZTs.

Comment: Generally we find convolution in domain by finding the multiplication of ZTs.  I am trying to do the reverse.  Find (actually checking) the time multiplicaiton using convolution of ZTs.

Comment: Do you have a _formula_ for the convolution of two $z$-transforms that is more detailed than $$(G\star H)(z) = G(z)\star H(z)?$$ that is, something comparable to $$(G\star H)(f) = G(f)\star H(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty G(f-\lambda)H(\lambda)\,\mathrm d\lambda$$ for the convolution of two Fourier transforms? and do you know how to _use_ the formula?

Comment: It's the last entry in [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties).

Comment: @MattL. I was asking the OP ....

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I thought that might speed up the whole thing a bit ... But the answer of how to *use* it is still left to the OP.

Comment: I know the formula but I find it a lot different from FT formula given above with (z/v) etc.  And how to find find this convolution using MATLAB to check that the inverse ZT is the multiplication of the sequences in time.

Answer (score 2):

The term-by-term product of the sequences $(a_0, a_1, a_2)$ and
$(b_0, b_1, b_2)$ is $(c_0, c_1, c_2) = (a_0b_0, a_1b_1, a_2b_2)$. The corresponding $z$-transforms are
\begin{align}
A(z) &= a_0 + a_1z^{-1} + a_2z^{-2}\\
B(z) &= b_0 + b_1z^{-1} + b_2z^{-2}\\
C(z) &= a_0b_0 + a_1b_1z^{-1} + a_2b_2z^{-2}
\end{align}
According to the formula in Wikipedia pointed out to you by MattL, $C(z)$ can be obtained from $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ via a *contour integral* in
the complex plane.  The *integrand* of the contour integral (which
is with respect to the complex variable $v$) is
\begin{align}
v^{-1}A(v)B\left(\frac zv\right) 
&= v^{-1}\left(a_0 + a_1v^{-1} + a_2v^{-2}\right)
\left(b_0 + b_1\left(\frac zv\right)^{-1} 
+ b_2\left(\frac zv\right)^{-2}\right)\\
&= \frac {a_0b_0 + a_1b_1z^{-1} + a_2b_2z^{-2}}{v}
+ \sum_{m=0}^2\sum_{n=0, n\neq m}^2 
\left(a_mb_nz^{-n}\right) v^{-m + n -1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where in that last sum in $(1)$, the exponent of $v$ in each term is either $\geq 0$ or $\leq -2$. In other words, if we regard each of the $8$ terms in that sum as a separate function of $v$, then the function
either has no poles inside the unit circle ($-m+n-1 \geq 0$) or 
has a pole of multiplicity
greater than $1$ at the origin ($-m+n-1 \leq -2$). 
Now, write the contour integral of the right side of
$(1)$ as the sum of $9$ different contour integrals and
apply Cauchy's integral theorem to evaluate each of these $9$ contour integrals. The conclusion is that the integrals of all the terms 
in that sum in $(1)$ integrate to $0$ while the contour integral
of $\displaystyle \frac {a_0b_0 + a_1b_1z^{-1} + a_2b_2z^{-2}}{v}$ 
(which has a single pole at the origin) gives the desired
$C(z) = a_0b_0 + a_1b_1z^{-1} + a_2b_2z^{-2}$. 
Generalization of all this to sequences of arbitrary lengths is
straightforward.

If you don't know
enough complex-variable theory to figure out why it is that the contour
integral of the first term in $(1)$ is just the numerator and why the integral of the other terms is $0$, then you
will not be able to carry out the verification that you desire.

Comment: It may be helpful to add that strictly speaking $D(v)$ is not a polynomial in $v$ because it also contains negative powers of $v$, and it is not independent of $z$, as the notation might suggest to the uninitiated. The conclusion of course remains true, because the only important thing is that $D(v)$ does not contain terms with $v^{-1}$.

Comment: @MattL. Thanks. It was late at night when I wrote my answer and forgot to include the poles at the origin of multiplicity greater than $1$.  have edited my answer to point all this out explicitly.

Comment: OK, I think this is clearer now. I guess the sum is meant as a double sum over $n$ and $m$ where both indices vary between $0$ and $2$, with $m\neq n$.

Comment: @MattL. Thanks. Yes, that is a double sum. I have edited the answer to include this as well as more explanations.